# syntax error non query c#

Tags: c#, mysql, executenonquery

for school I need to make a web application with c# and mysql.
In the application there is a registration page but when I click on the button to finish I get a syntax error that says that the execute.nonquery is wrong.
Can somebody help me ?

This is the code:

```
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gpopdrachtConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            string insertQ;
            insertQ = "Insert into tblWerknemer(Gebruikersnaam, Vnaam, Fnaam, Wachtwoord, Geboortedatum, Geboorteplaats, E-mailadres, Geslacht, Loon, gsmNummer, Nationaliteit, Gemeente, Postcode, StraatEnNr)";
            insertQ += "values(@gbr, @Vn, @Fn, @Ww, @GebD, @GebPl, @Email, @Geslacht, @Loon, @gsm, @Nat, @Gemeent, @Post, @Strtnr)";
            insertQ += "Insert into tbldiploma(school,NaamDiploma) Values(@school,@diploma)";
            insertQ += "Insert into tblpostcode(postcode,gemeente) Values(@Post,@Gemeent)";
            insertQ += "Insert into tblstatuut(omschrijving) Values(@omschrijving)";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            //= new MySqlCommand(insertQ, conn); 

            cmd.CommandText = insertQ;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gbr", txtgbr.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vn", txtVnaam.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fn", txtfnaam.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ww", txtww.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GebD", txtgdatum.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GebPl", txtgplaats.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtemail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Geslacht", checkgeslacht.SelectedItem.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@diploma", txtdiploma.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@school", txtschool.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Loon", txtloon.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@omschrijving", txtstatuut.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gsm", txtgsm.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nat", txtnat.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gemeent", txtgemeent.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Post", txtpost.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Strtnr", txtstrt.Text);

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
```

and this is the error:

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-mailadres, Geslacht, Loon, gsmNummer, Nationaliteit, Gemeente, Postcode, Straat' at line 1'

Comment: Code in question, not in images, please.

Comment: Also, does `INSERT INTO table (col) VALUES (@val)INSERT INTO table (col) VALUES (@val)` normally work for you? That's what the SQL you're building looks like. Note the `(@val)INSERT` part.

Comment: hello John, this is the first time I need to insert in more than 1 table, so I don't know if it normally works like this ..

Comment: It doesn't - and unless things have changed, MySQL doesn't allow multiple queries at once by default anyway.

Comment: So you suggest to create 4 different sql statements?

Comment: Jolien please read [here](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) about why you should post your code in your question, and please update your question accordingly by editing it. Note that I didn't downvote, however.

Comment: I changed it in the question. I'm sorry, I didn't know.

Comment: You shouldn’t use “-“ in column names

Answer (score 1):

You problem is a syntax near E-mailadres(the way you wrote it) try changing that to one name like emailaddres or email_adres.the dash(-) is causing you trouble

Comment: There are multiple problems. Either way, the code should be _in the question_.

Comment: Now I get an other error: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Insert into tbldiploma(school,NaamDiploma) Values('UGent','Boekhouder')Insert in' at line 1'

Comment: @JolienJansoone You can execute multiple `INSERT` statements with one `ExecuteNonQuery` call, but they _must_ be separated with semicolons (`;`). So change `Values(@school,@diploma)";` (for example) to `Values(@school,@diploma);";` (and same for all statements in your SQL string).

Comment: Try updating here to be  something like this,, @Post, @Strtnr);"; //add a semicolon
            insertQ += "Insert into tbldiploma(school,NaamDiploma) Values(@school,@diploma);";